# Bookmark lines that start with a year and month

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like following:

```
20110512192714
20794709157481
20121203175303
20794709157481
20210131201708
20211101050154
20220501022609
79776361952441
```

Now I want to select lines that start with a year and month from left side in notepad++ by regex.
Note that years must start from 2000 to 2023.
I tried following regex:

```
20(?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|20)[0-1][0-9]
```

above regex working good but have two problem:

1. Can't select whole line of targets and select piece of target line.
   (sometimes maybe length of numbers are not same)
2. It can't select
   some lines like following lines:

   20211101050154
   20220501022609

where is my regex problem?

Comment: Do you want to start matching with `^20(?:2[0-3]|[01]\d)` ? https://regex101.com/r/3E5VPW/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird it's good but how to select whole of target lines?

Comment: You can match the whole line if there are only digits with `^20(?:2[0-3]|[01]\d)\d*$` or else match the rest of the line with `^20(?:2[0-3]|[01]\d).*`

Comment: @Thefourthbird ye it's good, thanks for explaining solution to me. send as answer by explain that i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern `20(?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|20)[0-1][0-9]` matches:

20 followed by a range 00-09 or range 10-19 or 20 followed by either 00-19 or 01-19

---

If yo want to match a line that starts with 2000 - 2023 and should only contain digits:

```
^20(?:2[0-3]|[01]\d)\d*$
```

If you want to include matching a month from 1 - 12 with an optional leading zero:

```
^20(?:2[0-3]|[01]\d)(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\d*$
```

The year pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `20` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `2[0-3]` Match 20, 21, 22, 23
  - `|` Or
  - `[01]\d` Match from 00 to 19
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\d*` Match optional digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E5Ncsa/1).

If you want to match the rest of the line that could contain any character, you can change the last part of the pattern from `\d*$` to `.*`